# Injective homomorphism whose image is contained in the union of two conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

> Show that there exists injective homomorphism $\tau : \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \rightarrow S_{27}$  whose image is contained in the union of two conjugacy classes of $S_{27}$.

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{27}$ by Cayley theorem. In addition, I know that conjugacy classes in $S_{27}$ are defined by cycle structure.

Combining this, I need somehow to take the given isomorphism from Cayley theorem, and show that the image of it contained in the union of two conjugacy classes...

How can I do that?

Comment: Every nonzero element of your group has order 3 as it acts on itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G= \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. Then for $a \in G$ we define $L_a: G \to G$ by $x \to ax$. It's obviously a permutation of $G$ (viewed as $27$-element set). Then we know that the map $\gamma: G \to S_{27}$  defined by $a \to L_a$ is a homomorphism. In fact this is what the Cayley's Theorem tells us.

Now we'll prove that all $L_a$ for $a\not = e \in G$ the permutation has the same cycle structure, which means that all permutations are in the same conjugacy class. In $G$ each such element $a$ has order $3$ and thus we have that $L_a \circ L_a \circ L_a(x) = x$ and thus it's not hard to conclude that $L_a$ consists of 9 3-cycles. Thus we have that all $L_a$ for $a\not = e \in G$ have the same cycle structres and therefore are in the same conjugacy class.

Finally note that $L_e$ is in a conjugacy class of it's own. Hence the proof.

Comment: I think a bit of details is missing as to why $L_a$ consists of $9$ $3$-cycles. After all, not all elements of order $3$ in $S_{27}$ have this property.

Comment: @verret Could you please elaborate further? I mean it's obvious that $L_a$ has no fixed points and $L_a$ has order $3$. Thus each element has to be in $3$-cycle and so we must have $9$ of them.

Comment: I just meant the fact that $L_a$ has no fixed points. Of course it's obvious how to show this, but it's easy for a beginner to miss that this is needed.